# Function not returning anything

Tags: python, django

**My view**

```
def login(request):
    c = {}
    c.update(csrf(request))
    return render_to_response(request,
'login.html', c)

def auth_view(request):
    username = request.POST.get
('username', '')
    password = request.POST.get
('password', '')
    user = auth.authenticate
(username = username, password =
password)
    if user is not None:
       auth.login(request,user)
        if request.method == 'POST':
            return HttpResponseRedirect('accounts/loggedin/')
        else:
             Retun HttpResponseRedirect('accounts/invalid/')
```

Error occurs that function `auth_view` is returning nothing.

Comment: are you using django authentication?

Comment: what if this line not going through  `if user is not None:`?

Comment: Yes i'm using django authentication

Comment: You may wanna look at @login_required designer

Comment: You've mispelt `Retun`

Answer (score 1):

If the `user` is `None`, `auth_view` doesn't return anything. You must return an HttpResponse...