# I've trying to build a simple login page for my project

Tags: python, django

```
def login(request):
    c = {}
    c.update(csrf(request))
    return render_to_response(request,
'login.html', c)

def auth_view(request):
    username = request.POST.get
('username', '')
    password = request.POST.get
('password', '')
    user = auth.authenticate
(username = username, password =
password)
    if user is not None:
       auth.login(request,user)
        if request.method == 'POST':
            return HttpResponseRedirect('accounts/loggedin/')
        else:
             Return HttpResponseRedirect('accounts/invalid/')
```

*every time else statement executing... i dont know what is wrong*
.....
In my login page when i enter login details wheater its correct or not it always redirect to "accounts/invalid"

[Views.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/996aI.jpg)

Comment: Is this related to your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38258935/1324033)?

Comment: 1) is this a dupe of your old question, 2) give us some detail. What errors? What undesired effect

Comment: Every time if request.method == 'POST' has been ignored else statement executing every time whenevr i"ve entered the login details it redirects to 'account/invalid/' whether the details r corrct or not

Comment: Is that the full method? I can't see how it can even get into *that* else statement since you authenticate via *post* data, so when will the method *not* be POST? Besides, Python wouldn't know what to do with **Return** so it would never redirect.

Comment: So what should i do now

Comment: That's because user is never None, either its an Authenticated User Instance with an id or an instance of AnonymousUser, Try **if user:** as condition rather **if user is not None:** .

Comment: Not working with if user: sir @kapil_sachdev

Comment: @KapilSachdev - [`authenticate`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.authenticate) returns None. OP, you should create an [mcve]

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/996aI.jpg here is the code

Comment: Yeah you are right... Thanks @Sayse .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic isn't good, **if user is not None:** instead use **if user.is_anonymous:**

Try my logic

`def login(request):
    c = {}
    c.update(csrf(request))
    return render_to_response(request,
'login.html', c)`

`def auth_view(request):
    username = request.POST.get
('username', '')
    password = request.POST.get
('password', '')
    user = auth.authenticate
(username = username, password =
password)
    if user.is_anonymous:
       auth.login(request,user)
        if request.method == 'POST':
            return HttpResponseRedirect('accounts/loggedin/')
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('accounts/invalid/')`

**Note: Your return is in caps**

**Now it should work. Try it!!**

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `HttpResponseRedirect` use `render`

```
def something(request):
   if something:
      do something()
        if something == 'POST':
            return render(request, 'accounts/loggedin.html')
        else:
            return render(requset, 'accounts/invalid.html')
```